# How is the caret "^" being handled when doing a search with PrincipalSearcher?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Let's say I have a user called "John" in AD.

When I try to search for "^John" (with caret) using PrincipalSearcher, I would get "John" as a result. I'd expect the result to be null since "^John" user does not exist in AD.

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(context);
user.SamAccountName = "^John";
PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(user);
UserPrincipal result = search.FindOne();

// result here would be "John" instead of null
```

Now I know that some special characters are handled differently when doing a search with PrincipalContext (asterisk * symbol is used as wildcard) but I could not find some documentation on how the caret symbol is being handled by PrincipalSearcher.

Can anyone tell me on how caret is being handled in this situation?